# How to add an attribute in a Zorba XQuery?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, zorba

I have XML documents with the root node called `entity`. For each document, I want to count how many nodes it has with the name `tender` and add it as an attribute to `entity`.

```
import module namespace file = "http://expath.org/ns/file";

for $file in file:list("../api/entity/p/", true(), "??????.xml")
let $doc := doc(concat("../api/entity/p/", $file))
return
    update insert attribute number_of_tenders {count($doc//tender)} into $doc/entity
```

I was following http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/update_ext.xml, which is not for Zorba, but I guessed this is standard XQuery.

I get the error

```
6,69: static error [err:XPST0003]: invalid expression: syntax error, unexpected expression (missing comma "," between expressions?)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your update statement is not correct for Zorba. eXist implements an early draft of XQuery Update 1.0. I believe instead that Zorba correctly implemenets XQuery Update 1.0 specification, so your update should conform with this instead: http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-update-10/

Perhaps something like:

```
for $file in file:list("../api/entity/p/", true(), "??????.xml")
let $doc := doc(concat("../api/entity/p/", $file))
return
    insert node attribute number_of_tenders {count($doc//tender)} into $doc/entity
```

In particular have a read of http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-update-10/#id-insert

Comment: Here's a working example on Zorba: http://try.zorba.io/queries/xquery/U%2FcxnnwOm8RG0mpsMI2hBikeIeQ%3D In this example we use xquery scripting to both apply the update and return the result.